# ISO Archive vs Cd Image

Tags: iso-image, archiving, compact-disc

Is getting an image of a disc (eg with brasero) the same thing as going into the cd, selecting everything and putting it into a .iso archive (eg with 7zip or ubuntu's archive manager)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not the same.  For a disk that is only holding data, it probably won't make much of a difference, but some disk have things that would be copied incorrectly, or not at all by just a select all.

For example, if you selected and copied files into a new archive, you could not replicate a bootable CD like your operating system CD.

The [ISO 9660 aka CDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) has lots of meta-data, that you may need in some cases.

CDs can have [hard-links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) for example.  I have a ISO that fits on a CD ~500MB, but if you tried to a simple copy to the filesystem, it would appear to have over 1.2GB worth of data on it

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is no. It will record additional information like where the files on the disc were, which would make things like copying a bootable disc more effective.

If you were to copy a bootable disc just by selecting everything on the disk, and then burned the resulting files, it would not work. Taking the image using a program that generates and ISO would do the job properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same. If the CD ISO has special parameters (ie booting your computer) then just copying the the files from a CD to an ISO would not copy those special parameters.

Comment: I'm kind of scratching my head as to why you would upvote an answer that directly contradicts yours...

Comment: Read my comment. Up vote was ironically given for his sarcasm and my sarcasm for the up vote which contradicts my answer. It's a paradox.

Comment: Got it. Was just confused.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  It is the exact same thing. I don't know anything about "brasero" (or Ubuntu's archive manager or 7zip for that matter) , however .iso images are not compressed (a 700mb .iso fits perfectly onto a cd).

Comment: Even for bootable discs??? I believe, (as the the other answers that arrived at basically the same time) that you are mistaken. (hence the -1)

Comment: `brasero` is a cd-authoring tool, it will copy a cd using something like dd to make a bit-for-bit copy.  I am pretty sure he is asking if he can select files in file-manager and copy them into some kind of archive tool.  This is not the same at all.

Comment: @kobaltz Thanks!, I'll wind up deleting my answer though...

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks, Now I understand a bit better...